# Merge two lists into single list containing single character vectors R

Tags: r

Okay I'm stumped, I know there are answers about merging lists, and my attempt builds on those answers, but they don't return a single char vector. I have a function that merges lists but the values are separate character vectors:

I dont want the characters as separate strings

```
csc.list <- mapply(c, rep("CSC", 16), c(1:16), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

$CSC
[1] "CSC" "1"
$CSC
[1] "CSC" "2"
...
```

I don't know how to combine the characters in rows with a wierd heading

```
csc.list <- mapply(unlist, c(mapply(c, rep("CSC", 16), c(1:16), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))

CSC   CSC   CSC   CSC   CSC   ...
[1,] "CSC" "CSC" "CSC" "CSC" "CSC" ...
[2,] "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   ...
```

#### Desired Result of two merged lists

```
c("CSC 1", "CSC 2", "CSC 3", "CSC 4", "CSC 5", ... , "CSC 16")

[1] "CSC 1" "CSC 2" "CSC 3" "CSC 4" "CSC 5" ... "CSC 16"
```

Bonus if your answer scales to merging more than two, i.e. `n` lists into single vector of merged characters:

```
csc.list <- mapply(c, rep("CSC", 16), c(1:16), rep(".R", 16), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
lalalala <- f(csc.list)
```

#### Desired result of three merged lists

```
[1] "CSC 1.R" "CSC 2.R" ...
```

[image: cat]
<sub>(source: [placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com/200/100))</sub>

Comment: ? `paste(rep("CSC", 16), 1:16)` or `paste("CSC", 1:16)`
`

Comment: I was worried that the answer was as simple as rbind, but it's even simpler than rbind. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
csc.list <- mapply(c, rep("CSC", 16), c(1:16), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

#merge the list into a string
output<-sapply(csc.list, toString)
#remove the added commas
output<-gsub(",", "", output)
```

Comment: Why not just use `paste`?  Saves you from having to remove the commas. `sapply(csc.list, paste, collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 1):

This question is 3 years old at the time of writing this. However, I am adding this answer as it might help some people. What you are looking for is the `flatten_chr()` function in the `purrr` package.

```
csc.list <- mapply(c, rep("CSC", 16), c(1:16), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

library(purrr)
flatten_chr(csc.list)
```